# Javascript website issue

Tags: javascript, web, public-html

I'm very new to Javascript and programming all together. I've been trying to get this Javascript code to run on my website and I just can't get it to work.

```
var yourName = prompt("What is your name?");
if(yourName.length < 10) {
   confirm("Your name is less than 10 letters long!");
}
else {
   confirm("Your name is more than 10 letters long!");
}
```

I've tried saving this as a `.js` file and uploading it to the `public_html` folder with FileZilla and adding

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

to my index HTML file.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are your HTML file and JS file in the same directory?

Comment: your browser probably has a debug console, e.g. shift-ctrl-j in firefox/chrome. Use that to see what's happening.

Comment: Is the browser finding the file? (view-source and click on "script.js" and see if it returns the file)

Comment: do you have this code in between <script> tags and press F12 on your keyboard and run the script and write down what error(s) you are getting

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong? What does your browser's JavaScript console say? Does the browser's developer tools Net tab show the JavaScript file loading successfully?

Comment: So I tried just putting the actual code itself between <script> and </script> of running it from a separate file in the directory and it actually worked. However, the user has to finish the prompt before the rest of the page loads up is my only issue.